# log4j logger overwriting into jxl.log file

Tags: java, log4j, jxl

I am using log4j for logger purpose. At the same time I am also using JXL to read/write Excel file.
But instead of writing log into log4j logger file, it is writing into `jxl.log` file.

What can be issue?

Comment: have you checked your log4j config?

Comment: we do not have config file, we have log4j.properties file  
###############################################################################
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

###############################################################################
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\ABC\\XYZ.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have been using `jxl-2.6.3.jar` or similar version.

`Log4j` picks up the first configuration file with default file name ( i.e. `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` ) in your classpath if you haven't specified a specific name via JVM parameters. As jxl-2.6.3.jar contains a `log4j.xml` you ended up printing everything to `jxl.log` as defined in the `log4j.xml`

The best way to deal with these kind of problems is to run your application with `-Dlog4j.debug` JVM parameter. This would print a few line snippet when the log4j is initialized.

```
log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/C:/YourApp/WEB-INF/lib/jxl-2.6.3.jar!/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
...{Blah Blah Blah}
```

There are many ways in which you can solve this problem.

- Use the [**newer versions**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl) of `jxl` which doesn't contain `log4j.xml`.
- Make sure your log4j.properties file is on top of classpath.
- Remove the `log4j.xml` from the `jxl-2.6.3.jar` (Dirty solution).
- Pass the configuration file name in VM parameter as `-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties`. This would atleast make sure `log4j.xml` inside jxl-2.6.3.jar will not be used. (But what if another jar with same name as log4j.properties?).
- Rename your `log4j.properties` file to `log4j-yourApp.properties` and add VM parameter  `-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-yourApp.properties` This would definitely help and this is how it should be done to avoid these kind of situations.

More details on Log4j [**here**](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)